# Convert Number into Monthly Date

Tags: sql, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I have a field that gives me the day of the month. I need to convert that into a date to have my query pull users 5 days before that date. Can anyone help?

So I have a field called "Draft_Day_of_the_Month" and it can have a value of 4, 6, 25 etc.

I need to pull users 5 days before that date to send them an email. How would I convert that into a date field that then can be used?

Comment: Please review [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) and edit your question with more details.

Comment: Do you also have month and year fields?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No Month or Year fields. However for this issue, it pulls monthly. So if the field has the number 25, then the date would be Sept. 25, 2022. If the field has 6 it would be Sept. 6, 2022. The number in this field doesn't change. This is to pull when a statement notification goes out.